# Show that $X$ has no mean

Tags: statistics, means

$X$ is said to have a Cauchy distribution iff $X$ has a probability distribution of the form:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{a}{\pi(ax^2+x^2)} & \text{,$x>0$} \\
\ \ \ \ 0 & \text {,otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $a>0$

How can I show that $X$ has no mean?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36027/why-does-the-cauchy-distribution-have-no-mean

Comment: Incidentally, the pdf as written above is wrong. It should be $a^2$, not $ax^2$.

Comment: Yup, denominator should be pi(a^2+x^2).

Comment: And Cauchy distributions have support the line (-oo,+oo), not (0,+oo).

Comment: Duplicate of [Mean of a Cauchy Distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1015963) and of [Why does the Cauchy distribution have no mean if it's symmetric around 0?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/675473). Please search before asking: entering "mean of Cauchy distribution" is all it takes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Try to compute it:
$\mathbb{E}[X]$ *would* be equal to $$ \int_{(-\infty,\infty)} xf(x) dx$$
Does this integral exist (in a proper sense)? (i.e., is the function $x\mapsto x f(x)$ integrable on $(-\infty,\infty)$?)

> In particular, look at what asymptotically $xf(x)$ becomes when $x\to \infty$:$\frac{x}{a^2+x^2} \sim_{x\to\infty} ?$